# Text Scrolling Plugin for jQuery - Marquee doesn´t work on opera mini

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am create element in:

```html
<div class="marquee" style="overflow: hidden; font-weight:bold;white-space: nowrap;">
  Hello World!
</div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.marquee').marquee({
      pauseOnHover: true,
      duration: 30000,
      allowCss3Support: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

It works fine on browser like Chrome, Android Browser, Opera, etc. but on Opera Mini are not working.

M

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: I use under the plugin. http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin